# Odoo How to create a new model for Product Master with all the data in the product master

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I want to create a separate view for Product Master.I created a new model and tried like this.But when I checked in `database` no data is present in my new model.

> Code

```
class QuotationCreation(models.Model):
    _name='quotation.creation'

    xn_product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template')
    product=fields.Char(related = 'xn_product_id.name',string='Product')
```

How can I tranfer all the data from product master to this model.
I want to create a new model with existing data.How can I do that ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You want to display your own products list?

Comment: yes,I want to display my own product list

Comment: It is just simple, create your own action method and call the product master in it.

Comment: @Navi How to create a new `Action` (`Action` at top) and by clicking that action I want to go to `Quotation`'s form view with some products.Want to ask as a new question ?

Comment: @Navi I want to create a new model with existing data.How can I do that ?

Comment: It is not possible with new model.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for the reply :-)

Comment: welcome.........

Answer (score 1):

For populating your new model with your existing `product.template` table records, you have to run a for loop in your `odoo shell`, because this are existing data that you cannot fire any event on `create` method. For example:

```
ProductTemplates = env['product.template'].search([])
for pt in ProductTemplates:
  env['quotation.creation'].create({'xn_product_id': pt.id})
env.cr.commit()
```

OR you can even export all database id from product template list view and import that on `quotation.creation` list view with no other field which will create all the records in your new table.

For future records, you can just inherit `product.template` models `create()` method and create a corresponding `quotation.creation` record in it.